# use numpy.linalg.multi_dot for 3-dimensional arrays of (N, M, M) shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Is that any reasonable way to use np.linalg.multi_dot() function with Nx2x2 arrays like functools.reduce(np.matmul, Nx2x2_arrays)?
Please, see example below.

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce

m1 = np.array(range(16)).reshape(4, 2, 2)
m2 = m1.copy()
m3 = m1.copy()

reduce(np.matmul, (m1, m2, m3))
```

result - 4x2x2 array:

```
array([[[    6,    11],
        [   22,    39]],

       [[  514,   615],
        [  738,   883]],

       [[ 2942,  3267],
        [ 3630,  4031]],

       [[ 8826,  9503],
        [10234, 11019]]])
```

As you see, np.matmul treats 4x2x2 3-D arrays like 1-D arrays of 2x2 matrices.
Can I do the same using np.linalg.multi_dot() instead of reduce(np.matmul) and, if yes, will it lead to any performance improvement?

Answer (score 2):

`np.linalg.multi_dot()` tries to optimize the operation by finding the order of dot products that leads to the fewest multiplications overall.

As all your matrices are square, the order of dot products does not matter and you will always end up with the same number of multiplications.

Internally, `np.linalg.multi_dot()` doesn't run any C code but merely calls out to `np.dot()`, so you can do the same:

```
functools.reduce(np.matmul, (m1, m2, m3))
```

or simply

```
m1 @ m2 @ m3
```

Comment: Thank you @NilsWerner! You confirmed my reasoning about the equivalence of these methods for same shape square matrices. But later I've realized that I can just check on 2x2 matrices. 
Results are following (for 1 million for loop iterations):
- 7.24 sec. for np.linalg.multi_dot((m1, m2, m3));
- 3.25 sec. for reduce(np.dot,(m1, m2, m3));
- 2.52 sec. for reduce(np.matmul,(m1, m2, m3));
- 2.31 sec. for m1 @ m2 @ m3.

I still don't have an answer about possibility of using np.linalg.multi_dot with 3D-arrays, but it seems matmul will be more useful in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `np.einsum()`:

```
np.einsum('ijk,ikl,ilm->ijm',m1,m2,m3)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about this function! Thank you, that looks great but I'm not sure if np.einsum() will be suitable for variable number of matrices (yes, it's my fault, I have not specified in the question that matrices can be more then 3).